# How to change default installation path for vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

After changing my windows user folder (C:/Users/{this}), i can't use "open with code". I've tried to reinstall app, but its asks for an old windows user folder to install the app. I've installed vscode with .zip but "open with code" feature still can't find the app, and keeps asking for my old path to vscode (C:/Users/{oldUserName}). So the Question is more about: how to configurate or delete this "open with code" feature?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this by replacing all old paths in regedit with the new one, you can find all with Crtl + F and search for your old user name foder